# Syntax error on INSERT INTO command in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I am very new to this and using Access
I am attempting to insert into table `EMPLOYEE`
a column called `MIDDLENAME`
and for one employee-id a value called `Junior`
what have I done wrong here - I get "Syntax error on `INSERT INTO` command"

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
(MIDDLENAME)
VALUES
[JUNIOR]
(WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IS 'E9876543)';
```

Comment: what has join tag have to do? what exactly do u mean in you title?

Comment: Did you meant to UPDATE the existing record?

Comment: this combined two questions I was wanting to ask sorry it made sense the first time I posted

Comment: no join no nested query - the heading relates to different question sorry

Comment: The question isn't totally clear. Are you trying to update an existing record, or insert a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If the column doesn't yet exist you need to modify the table structure first, and then run the `UPDATE` below:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN MIDDLENAME TEXT(25); -- or whatever length
```

The question isn't entirely clear to me, but it *sounds* like you're trying to update an existing employee by changing his middle name:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET MIDDLENAME = 'JUNIOR'
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 'E9876543';
```

You had a few syntax errors in your query:

- `EMPLOYEE_ID IS 'E9876543)` ... use `=` and not `IS`
- () around your `WHERE` clause
- Probably a misplaced `)` in your string literal ... `'E9876543)'`

Also, be careful about how you use the terms *insert* and *update* when it comes to database queries.

Comment: Im adding a currently non existent column called Middlename

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (MIDDLENAME) VALUES ('JUNIOR') WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 'E9876543';

Comment: now error says query input must contain table or query